# How do you write a java unit test of a class method that does not return a value?

Tags: java, unit-testing

I am a newbie to Java unit testing and need help writing a unit test that just needs to handle 2 paths of an "if" statement where the method has no return value.

```
public class Consumer extends KafkaConsumer {
    private final MessageService service;

    public Consumer(MessageService service) {
        this.service = service;
    }

    @Override
    protected void processRecords(ConsumerRecords<Long, String> records) {
        for (ConsumerRecord<Long, String> records) {
            if (record.value().startsWith("{")) {
                OldFormatMessageObject mo = new OldFormatMessageObject(record.value());
                service.processMessage(mo);
            } else if (record.value().startsWith("metadata")) {
                NewFormatMessageObject mo = new NewFormatMessageObject(record.value());
                service.processMessage(mo);
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: You need to use mocks here, and then verify the interaction between the unit and the mocks. Well, try using Mockito, for example.

Comment: `OldFormatMessageObject` and `NewFormatMessageObject` have a common superclass right? What it is?

Comment: They are both standalone classes.

Answer (score 1):

## What to test?

Strictly speaking, there are actually 3 paths in branching logic to test:

1. if `startsWith("{")` then `MessageService#processMessage(OldFormatMessageObject)` is called.
2. if `startsWith("metadata")` then `MessageService#processMessage(NewFormatMessageObject)` is called.
3. otherwise nothing happens.

It would be nice if "iteration" logic is unit tested as well (`for` loop).

## How to test?

We have to verify, that correct method of `MessageService` is called.

For this, we can use `MessageService` mock, which will be injected to `Consumer` via constructor.

Using mockito [1], it might look like this:

```
...
private static final String TEST_TOPIC = "test.topic";

@Mock
private MessageService messageServiceMock;

// Tested instance
private Consumer consumer;

@BeforeEach
public void beforeEach() {
    consumer = new Consumer(messageServiceMock);
}

@Test
public void newMessageFormatIsHandled() {
    // Given
    final String expectedValue = "my-expected-value";

    // When
    consumer.processRecords(testSingleConsumerRecords(expectedValue));

    // Then
    verify(messageServiceMock, times(1)).processMessage(new NewFormatMessageObject(expectedValue));
    // OR
    verify(messageServiceMock, times(1)).processMessage(isA(NewFormatMessageObject.class));
}

...

private static ConsumerRecords<Long, String> testSingleConsumerRecords(String expectedValue) {
    final Map<TopicPartition, List<ConsumerRecord<Long, String>>> records = new LinkedHashMap<>();
    final ConsumerRecord<Long, String> record = new ConsumerRecord<>(TEST_TOPIC, 1, 0, 100L, expectedValue);
    records.put(new TopicPartition(TEST_TOPIC, 0), Collections.singletonList(record));

    return new ConsumerRecords<>(records);
}
```

Note, that if `MessageService` has interface, you don't even need any mock framework, and provide "mocked" instance to your unit test cases, but mock framework makes tests quite more readable.

---

[1] https://site.mockito.org

Comment: I'm not sure what to do with your "testSingleConsumerRecords(expectedValue) method.

Comment: Simply create test `ConsumerRecords` instance - I've updated answer (feel free to modify).

Comment: I get a NullExceptionPointer for the "service" variable in my ProcessRecords method.

Comment: That means, your mock was not initialized. Consult the documentation of the mock framework you are using - in case you are using mockito with JUnit  5, do not forget to annotate your test class with `@ExtendWith(MockitoExtension.class)`.